# Calculating output on Neural Network

Tags: c#, output, neural-network, aforge

I am trying to create neural network and I am using aforge framework. I have 3 inputs, 20 outputs data. inputs like this: 0.4397 1.4492 0.57 , 0.4296 1.5271 0.615 etc. And outputs data like this: [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] , [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] etc. I am calculating outputs look like: [image]

I know, outputs must getting [0,1] but here [-1,1]. I have normalized train data(divide 100) and output data(divide 100).

What is my problem? Thanks in advance. (sorry my english)

Comment: why do you think the output are supposed to be in the range of [0,1] ?

Comment: Backpropagation function getting [0,1] output. Not - value. I think my problem is normalization and denormalization but I don't know how can i succeed.

Comment: Please add to your question your code

Comment: I have just told problem. Code about 2500 lines. You shouldn't want to look, be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of each node of a multi-layer perceptron (which i suppose you are using) does not lie in [0, 1] or [-1, 1], but in [-∞, +∞]. In this way MLPs can perform either regression or classification. In your case, since you are using it for a classification problem, the output is passed through an activation function, which limits the output to a specific interval.

Two commonly used such functions are the sigmoid function and the hyperbolic tangent function, which map the output to [0, 1] and [-1, 1] respectively. In your case, the framework most likely uses the hyperbolic functions as default activation. You find that parameter and it is to sigmoid/logistic or something similar.

PS: Regardless of the above, are you sure the problem you are trying to solve is formulated correctly?? 3 inputs and 20 outputs seems very unlikely for a classification problem.

Comment: It's true. "3 inputs and 20 outputs seems very unlikely for a classification problem." :(